# Is this bug in Reputation List?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, profile-page

I have checking my Reputation changes date-wise
I found a row which is showing this text change of 0 its not  `positive == negative` cause i have checked the show removed posts

You must be seeing the days missing between dates like Oct 11 then Oct 15 and then Oct 19

but it shows **0 for Oct 22**  and also state **There were no net reputation changes on this day**
and I have also checked the check box which says **Show removed Tags**

#### why Oct 22 is there ??

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means there were reputation changes, but not any net changes - for example someone upvoted a post and then retracted it.

It shows that **something** happened, vs nothing at all.

Comment: The last line convinced me that showing that message has some point. +1